# Identifier field are not included in Activities: list Meet report

Tags: google-admin-sdk

Good day everyone,

was trying to use the Admin SDK Reports API to get info about Google Meet.
want to see who attended and how long does each person in the conference.
However, I cannot seem to get the email address of each attendee instead I only get the display name.

tried the fields option in API explorer to include the Identifier but got an error instead. Also, don't where or if there is a documentation about option Fields.

Please see attached image

[image]

If I set the fields empty I got a successful result but can't see the Identifier field which supposedly has the email address of the attendee.

[image]

My goal is to have this displayed in the result
[image]
Hopely got the answer right,
Thank you

Comment: Were the participants of the meeting your domain users or other users / unverified?

Comment: @ziganotschka the participants are directly invited through their email.

Comment: But do they belong to your Google Domain (are you a GSuite user and you have a Google Domain?) or from another domain?

Comment: @ziganotschka they don't belong to my domain. 
and yes I have a Gsuite.

Comment: This is not the correct way to filter the fields returned (the error). I am looking for the correct notation on those specific fields.

Answer (score 0):

The [documentation](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/reports/v1/appendix/activity/meet) specifies:

> identifier_type
>   email_address 
>   The participant's email address **for in-domain participants**.

**This means that you are not allowed to see the emails of domain-external participants.**

I assume it is implemented this way for safety reasons.

Comment: Thanks for the info, seems that it is impossible to get this info for external users